# the top property in not working on this code

Tags: html, css

in the below code the top property inside the id "#bad" is does not make any effect, can any one help me. it's made some effect when i used it with
some other codes.
html code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rise.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="good">
            <div id="vahid">
                <div id="one">

                    <img src="image1.jpg"  id="boom"><br><br><br><br><br>
                    <!--button-->
                    <img src="button.jpg" id="button"><br><br><br><br>
                    <!--icons-->
                        <span class="local">
                            <img src="img.jpg">
                            <img src="img1.jpg">
                            <img src="img2.jpg">
                            <img src="img3.jpg">
                        </span><br><br><br><br>
                        <span class="local">
                            <img src="img4.jpg">
                            <img src="img5.jpg">
                            <img src="img6.jpg">
                            <img src="img7.jpg">
                        </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="isnani">
                 <div id="third">
                    <p >
                        <span class="fourth">Dashboard</span>      
                        <span class="fifth">  + New</span>
                    </p>
                    <!--<p class="fourth">&nbsp;</p>
                    <p id="fort"><input type="text" placeholder="search your project here..." ></p>
                    <div id="jump"><img  src="search.jpg" height="20px" width="10px"></div>-->

                    <p id="sixth">    Welcome to Flatkit</p>
                    <p id="seventh"> Bootstrap 4 Web App Kit With Angular js</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bad">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css :

```
#good{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#bad{
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #023b3b;
    top:-80%;
}
#vahid{
    float: left;
    width: 7%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #023b3b;
}
#isnani{
    float: left;
    width: 93%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: bisque;
}
#one {
  display:block;
  background-color: #023b3b;
   /* width:60px;
    height: 867px;*/
}
#boom{
    margin-top: 30%;
    height: 5%;
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;


}
.local img {
    height: 2.5%;
    width:30%;
    margin :10px 0px 10px 20px;
}

/*isnani starts here*/
#third{  float:left;
    width:100%;
     height: 15%;
    border-color:white; 
border-style : solid;
background-color : white;

}
.fourth{
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}
.fifth{
    color: #808080;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    margin-left: 1%;

}
#sixth{
     font-family: sans-serif;
     font-size:150%;
    color:#666666;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    /*top: -2%;/
   /* line-height: 3%; */


}
#seventh{
    position: absolute;
     top: 11%;
    color: #808080;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
    margin-left: 1.8%;
    margin-top: 1.5%;

    /*line-height: 3%;*/

}
#fort{
    float: right;
    margin-top: -65px;
    margin-right: 80px;
}

#button{
    margin-left: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    hyphens: 20%;
}
```

in the above code the top property inside the id "#bad" is does not make any effect, can any one help me. it's made some effect when i used it with
some other codes.

Comment: But you don't have any content in your `#bad` div, so won't this collapse the div altogether - hence no styling being applied? Your question is a little unclear - could you clarify what you mean by "is does not make any effect"?

Comment: @GeoffJames It does have width and height properties, so I don't think it will collapse

Comment: @Justinas - this is true, thanks. It is a bit unclear what the question is, though. **"is does not make any effect"** doesn't seem to make much sense to me...

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @geoff james:  hey friend ,...look at the id #bad,it  produce a background with a size 35% x 100%  with a colour given inside it,when using top property ,the background is needed to move upward.just look at the example http://codepen.io/dreamhunter/pen/RRvbbW?editors=1100

Comment: i want the same effect here...

Comment: @Justinas - I stand by my previous comment - https://jsfiddle.net/15hntkxb/ look at the second `#bad` `div`. Add some text, and watch it "appear"...

Comment: @dreamhunter - if you'd had clarified this in your OP it would have been much easier to understand. See my jsfiddle in previous comment as to why. Justinas is completely right with the positioning (I'm not disputing that), so if you do update the position, you *should* end up with some height and background etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For properties `top`/`bottom`/`left`/`right` to take effect element must be positioned non-statically - have position `relative`/`absolute`/`fixed`.

Apply position to your `#bad`

Comment: yeah...that is it.